# Current time from SQL Server to PHP for compare

Tags: php, sql-server, time, php-mssql

Need get info, is EndDate expired or not (EndDate is row, where typed info about date of buyed user premium)

```
connectuser2db();
$bile_sql = "SELECT EndDate FROM tbl_rfuser WHERE Serial = '" . $userdata['serial'] . "'";
if (!($bile_result = mssql_query($bile_sql))) {
    echo "Unable to select query the Billing table";
    exit;
 }

$bilel = mssql_fetch_array($bile_result);          
$userdata['Enddate'] = $bilel['EndDate'];
$t_logd = $bilel['EndDate'];

echo $t_logd;
```

result like Jul 14 2020 02:36:00:000PM (if EndDate in smalldatetime data type)

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo $time;
```

result like 2020-07-15 14:51:21

If i use $time in this row, it update enddate to curent time:

```
$t_login = $userdata["lastlogintime"]; // last user login in game (from mssql) Jul 15 2020 02:36:00:000PM
$t_logd = $bilel['EndDate']; // Premium EndDate (from mssql) Jul 14 2020 02:36:00:000PM
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // current time (from php) like 2020-07-15 14:51:21
 if( $t_logd <= $t_login ) 
 { connectuser2db();
$user_update = "UPDATE tbl_rfuser SET EndDate='" . $time . "' WHERE Serial= '" . $userdata["serial"] . "'";
 mssql_query($user_update); }
```

It succesfully compare "lastlogin" and "enddate", and if account is new or user be online last time before EndDate expired - change EndDate to current time, that succesfully takes from $time.
But if user login after EndDate, it not works

Want this compare:

```
if( $t_logd <= $t_login ) //working now
```

Change to compare like:

```
if( $t_logd <= $time ) // not working now
```

Help please
How can I take current time from mssql or change $time for something, that can compare?
Tried strtotime, but can't do it (sql server check it in miliseconds, but my php old and can't use date("Y-m-d H:i:s:v") format)

Comment: Hello i don't understand what you want , but if you want current time from mssql you can do it like this " select EndDate,current_timestamp() as now FROM tbl_rfuser .......... "

Comment: You **need** to fix that huge injection issue you have. `WHERE Serial = '" . $userdata['serial'] . "'"` is incredibly dangerous code. *Always* **Parametrise** your queries.

Comment: What is your actual PHP version (you are using an unsupported PHP extension, so probably your PHP version is before 5.3)?

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.17 (that use mssql_query, not sql_query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that the [MSSQL PHP extension](http://MSSQL%20PHP%20extension) is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 7.0.0, but if you want a solution, you may try the following:

- Specify how the datetime values are returned from the SQL Server by setting the `mssql.datetimeconvert` option in your `php.ini` file to `Off`. When this option is `On` the datetime values are returned converted to SQL server settings. When this option is `Off` the datetime values are returned in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` format.
- Use `date_create()` to create and compare the dates as PHP datetime objects.

The next simplified example demonstrates this approach (tested with PHP 5.2.9):

```
<?php
// Connection
$server   = 'server,port';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';
$conn = mssql_connect($server, $username, $password);
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".mssql_get_last_message();
    exit;
}
mssql_select_db($database, $conn);

// Statement
$sql = "SELECT DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS [DateTime]";
$stmt = mssql_query($sql, $conn);
if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".mssql_get_last_message();
    exit;
}

// Results
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
    $datetime1 = date_create($row['DateTime']);
}
$datetime2 = date_create();

// Compare dates
echo ($datetime1 <= $datetime2) ? 'Result: <=' : 'Result: >';

// End
mssql_free_result($stmt);
mssql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Working! Just need change in php.ini "mssql.datetimeconvert" and compare: if( $t_logd <= $time ). Before $t_logd = result like Jul 14 2020 02:36:00:000PM, after result like 2020-07-15 14:51:21.
Sorry for long response, go sleep when hosting give me enable to php.ini. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [GETDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql):

```
UPDATE tbl_rfuser SET EndDate=GETDATE() WHERE Serial= ...
```

Comment: $time is already worked for update date, not here trouble.
Need do compare enddate to curent time, for check, need do UPDATE or skip step